# How to generate all possible ways of labeling (classifying) a set of objects using a set of labels in python?

Tags: python, combinations

Assume that we have a set of objects:

```
set_of_objects = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

and a set of classes:

```
set_of_classes = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

How can we generate all ways of classification of the set of objects into all possible classes in the set of classes in python?

An example output would be something like this:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
[[1,2],[3],[]]
[[1,2,3],[],[]]
[[3],[2],[1]]
and so on...
```

The number of all ways that we can classify n objects into k classes is: k ^ n, because we can assign every of n objects into k classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recursive algorithm to produce the partition:

```
import itertools

def part(lst, n):
    if n <= 1:
        # single answer for 1 partition
        yield [lst]
    else:
        for m in range(len(lst)+1):
            for head in itertools.combinations(lst, m):
                nothead = [x for x in lst if x not in head]
                for tail in part(nothead, n-1):
                    yield [list(head)]+tail

def partition(n):
    lst = list(range(n))
    for x in part(lst, n):
        print(x)
```

Example: `partition(3)`:

```
[[], [], [0, 1, 2]]
[[], [0], [1, 2]]
[[], [1], [0, 2]]
[[], [2], [0, 1]]
[[], [0, 1], [2]]
[[], [0, 2], [1]]
[[], [1, 2], [0]]
[[], [0, 1, 2], []]
[[0], [], [1, 2]]
[[0], [1], [2]]
[[0], [2], [1]]
[[0], [1, 2], []]
[[1], [], [0, 2]]
[[1], [0], [2]]
[[1], [2], [0]]
[[1], [0, 2], []]
[[2], [], [0, 1]]
[[2], [0], [1]]
[[2], [1], [0]]
[[2], [0, 1], []]
[[0, 1], [], [2]]
[[0, 1], [2], []]
[[0, 2], [], [1]]
[[0, 2], [1], []]
[[1, 2], [], [0]]
[[1, 2], [0], []]
[[0, 1, 2], [], []]
```

Comment: I do not mean Cartesian product because it does not give me any partitioning!

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Thanks. It works. Of course I am going to wait for more answers to see if some more efficient methods exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself but I will not mark it as answered to see if more efficient methods exist for that. my solution:

```
set(itertools.product(set_of_classes, repeat=len(set_of_objects))
```

In fact it will raise the set set_of_classes to (Cartesian) power of len(set_of_objects). Any better ideas?